# Connect to Neo4j database from c++ program

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I have trouble connecting to a Neo4j database (running in my Neo4j Desktop) in my C++ program.

Here are my connection details:
bolt://localhost:11003
username: neo4j
password: pass

I tried this:

```
#include <neo4j-client.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    neo4j_client_init();

    /* use NEO4J_INSECURE when connecting to disable TLS */
    neo4j_connection_t *connection =
            neo4j_connect("neo4j://neo4j:pass@localhost:11003", NULL, NEO4J_INSECURE);
    if (connection == NULL)
    {
        neo4j_perror(stderr, errno, "Connection failed");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    neo4j_result_stream_t *results =
            neo4j_run(connection, "RETURN 'hello world'", neo4j_null);
    if (results == NULL)
    {
        neo4j_perror(stderr, errno, "Failed to run statement");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    neo4j_result_t *result = neo4j_fetch_next(results);
    if (result == NULL)
    {
        neo4j_perror(stderr, errno, "Failed to fetch result");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    neo4j_value_t value = neo4j_result_field(result, 0);
    char buf[128];
    printf("%s\n", neo4j_tostring(value, buf, sizeof(buf)));

    neo4j_close_results(results);
    neo4j_close(connection);
    neo4j_client_cleanup();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I compiled as g++ main.cpp -o main -lneo4j-client

and run as ./main

I got Connection failed: Connection refused

Please help!
Thanks!